# FOR EACH Loop DAX

Tags: for-loop, powerbi, dax

I have a table of excel data called "Export" that I imported into Power BI.  I want to create a second table that lists normalization of my data.

I have some script someone else did for me in excel but I don't know how it can be converted into DAX.
Column V is equal to Aluminum and X is Boron in this example.

````
```
Dim User As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Set Ws = ActiveSheet
LastRow = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'****Aluminum
Range("V:V").EntireColumn.Insert (Shift = xlToRight)
Range("V1").Value = "Norm_Al"
Range("v2:V" & LastRow).Formula = "=IfError(Sum(U2 / O2 * 100), """")"
Range("v2:V" & LastRow).Formula = Range("v2:V" & LastRow).Value

'****Boron
Range("X:X").EntireColumn.Insert (Shift = xlToRight)
Range("X1").Value = "Norm_B"
Range("X2:X" & LastRow).Formula = "=IfError(Sum(W2 / O2 * 100), """")"
Range("X2:X" & LastRow).Formula = Range("X2:X" & LastRow).Value
```
````

Expected Results are attached
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhA7g.png)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a second table that lists normalization of my data.

In PowerBI, you don't use DAX to normalize your data like you (can) do in SQL by creating normalized views. instead, you restructure/normalize your tables in PowerQuery.